# regexp_like to selects rows where an attribute string contains several different words

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select

A bit new to regexp and looking for some help understanding some of the capabilities. I'am currently trying to select some sets of data that start with a word followed by a space and then several possible words.

Example 1:
I am basically looking to select data such as Product1 green, Product1 red, Product1 blue (green, red or blue basically) but not:
xyz Product1, Product1 black, Product1 white, Product1 garbage red.

I have tried to the following queries with not much success:

```
Where regexp_like(item, 'Product1 [green | red | blue]');
Where regexp_like(item, 'Product1 [green, red, blue]');
Where regexp_like(item, '^Product1 [green, red, blue]');
```

Hypothetically, does anybody know of a way I could also implement an 'AND', for example selecting items which contain the words green and red in the same attribute.

Example 2:
Similar situation, but trying to match a word after a punctuation

```
Where regexp_like (job, 'Commerce [[:punct:]] .*');
```

With this query I am looking to select jobs which have
Commerce - test
Commerce : abcdefg

These queries are not working as I would expect them to and I'm not able to quite figure out why. I am assuming I have misunderstood the construct of these regular expressions.

Any help / explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For the first, try the following

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEM, '^Product1.*(green|red|blue)')
```

or

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEM, '^Product1 (green|red|blue)')
```

or

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEM, '^Product1 +(green|red|blue)')
```

depending on what you expect after the `Product1` - the first case allows zero or more characters of any kind, the second requires that there be a single space after `Product1`, and the third requires one or more blanks after `Product1`.

Not sure where you're going exactly on the second one.  If you really want strings that begin with 'Commerce', followed by a space, followed by a punctuation character, another space, and then anything, try

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(JOB, '^Commerce [:punct:] .*');
```

If instead of a punctuation character you're looking for either ':' or '-', try

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(JOB, '^Commerce [:-] .*');
```

I'm no great expert on regular expressions but I'll try to offer some explanations:

- `^` requires that the following element be at the beginning of the string.  Thus, in the first case `^Product1` means "'Product1' must be at the the start of the string".
- In regular expressions parentheses are used to group expressions, so in the first case `(green|red|blue)` are grouped together.
- `|` is a logical OR, so `(green|red|blue)` means "must be one of 'green' or 'red' or 'blue'".
- Square brackets are used for character classes.  You can use either predefined classes, such as :punct: or :space:, or you can make up your own as in `[:-]`.  During regular expression interpretation a square bracket character class, no matter how long, represents a single character in the string being matched.  So in the regular expression `^Commerce [:-] .*` the character class `[:-]` means "look for either a colon or a dash".  If you want to indicate that you expect multiple occurrences of characters in the class, one after another, use one of the repetition operators (`*` or `+`) after the class - so `[abc]*` would match all of `abcabcabc`.

Also keep in mind that in a regular expression every character means something, so you can't use whitespace to make regular expressions more legible because the whitespace becomes something that will be looked for when the expression is interpreted.

Share and enjoy.

---

**Edit**

Didn't notice your question about `AND` earlier.  A simple way to AND together multiple expressions is to just put them one after another.  To look for (green|red|blue), followed by a space, followed by (green|red|blue) a simple expression would be

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEM, '^Product1 (green|red|blue) (green|red|blue)')
```

If potentially multiple spaces were to be allowed between the colors

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEM, '^Product1 (green|red|blue) +(green|red|blue)')
```

could be used.

Resistance is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. Wont this allow combinations like 'Product1xasdasdgreen' (because of the any character symbol)?. Can you explain how this would take into account the "words" being distinct (for example: Product 1 <space> green/red/blue). Thanks!

Comment: Apparently I added the second example while you were writing your comment - have a look at it.  I don't understand what you mean by "...the 'words' being distinct".  Please edit your post and add additional examples of what should or should not match.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1523257 - hadn't noticed your query about AND logic before, so added this at the end of my answer.